# events and threading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, events, event-handling

suppose I have:

```
ethernet_adapter.PacketArrived += (s, e) => 
{
    //long processing...
};
```

processing may take a long time and while it was in the middle another packet has arrived. What happens next: the processing gets done and then another event is fired or perhaps new event is fired immediately but on a new thread?

Comment: What type of object is `ethernet_adapter`?

Comment: @JimMischel it's a third party library type `ICaptureDevice`. I think I got the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not assume. It could be anything  depending upon how event is raised by type (of `ethernet_adapter` object).

If it is synchronous operation, new event will not be raised until current operation is in progress.

If it is asynchronous operation, new event will be raised immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are this is a synchronous operation. The only way it is going to happen on another thread is if the object that raises the event does so on another thread, or if you do in the handler. There are numerous ways to do this, but using [`System.Threading.Tasks.Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) would generally be preferred if using .NET 4.

Consider carefully how you want your application to behave. Simply processing each packet on a new thread could cause packets to be handled out of order. You may want to queue them up and have a background thread handle them at that point. Or you may not need to do anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can queue up the whole task in ThreadPool as followes.

```
ethernet_adapter.PacketArrived += (s, e) => 
{
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem("long processing item");
};
```

or you can create task(.net 4.0) for every thread.

Comment: How is this related to OP question?

Comment: each long processing item can be queue in the threadpool and will be served accordingly.I hope I have  understood the problem.

Comment: I think, question is, "what is the behavior" and not "how to make async handling"

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly there is a method in your `ethernet_adapter` class:

```
protected virtual void OnPacketArrived(PacketArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler<PacketArrivedEventArgs> handler = this.PacketArrived;

    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

So long processing synchronous subscriber (as in your example) would block internal enumeration over all the subscribers. BUT! It may not block subsequent calls to `OnPacketArrived` if `ethernet_adapter` invokes it on a different thread each time - so you will get two concurrent long processing, and so on.

As an example, have a look at the `Socket` implementation: it's async methods cause completion callbacks to be invoked on IOCP threads - different each time while there is any in the IO `ThreadPool`.